Gunicorn + Flask + GCR(Google cloud RUN) does not work properly on GCP
I have developed an algorithm in python and deployed it on GCP Cloud RUN using docker image. attached alognwith is the dockerfile for the same.

# Command to run the application
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "main:app", "--workers", "4", "--timeout", "600", "--preload"]


The problem is that when I trigger the code on GCR, it runs unevenly...it returns a 504 error   Also, the cloud RUN is configured with 4 CPU's and 16 GB memory. I have set max instances on GCR to be 5 and max concurrent request per instance to be 10 . how should the gunicorn command look like ?

Please have a look at this documentation.

Hi, I was able to resolve this by keeping timeout as 3600. Since, the code was taking more than 600 seconds( as defined earlier ) to execute end to end, the run failed. Though, keeping it as 3600 did the trick for me.

1. Timeout Issue:
By default, a Cloud Run request can run for up to 5 minutes (300 seconds). If your worker takes longer than this, Cloud Run will terminate it with a SIGKILL.
How to Increase Timeout:
You can configure the timeout for your service using either the GCP Console or the command line. The maximum timeout is 60 minutes (3600 seconds).
Command to Set Timeout (for up to 60 minutes):
gcloud run services update <SERVICE_NAME> --timeout=<TIME_IN_SECONDS>
For example, to set the timeout to 10 minutes (600 seconds):
gcloud run services update <SERVICE_NAME> --timeout=600
2. Out of Memory (OOM) Issue:
If your Cloud Run container is being killed by a SIGKILL, it might be running out of memory. Cloud Run uses resource constraints, and when your container exceeds the memory limit, it is killed.
How to Increase Memory:
Cloud Run allows you to allocate up to 32 GB of memory per container. You can increase the memory limit to prevent the OOM issue.
gcloud run services update <SERVICE_NAME> --memory=<MEMORY_LIMIT>
For example, to set the memory limit to 2 GB:
gcloud run services update <SERVICE_NAME> --memory=2Gi

I was able to resolve this by keeping timeout as 3600. Since, the code was taking more than 600 seconds( as defined earlier ) to execute end to end, the run failed. Though, keeping it as 3600 did the trick for me
